# Delphi: image with alpha blending capabilities

Tags: delphi, image, png, components, alpha

Is there some simple component that could display PNG 32-bit images and alpha-blend it to another image on mouse enter and on mouse leave? Or even just a simple image that can load 32-bit PNG and additionally would have Alpha parameter...

I suppose I could use some skin library (alphacontrols?) or some graphics library, but for some simple purely visual effects that would be quite an overkill and I can't seem to find a simple one that does it for me and would work on Glass surface as well...

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite a component, but here is a link to a good article on how to do it yourself. Its just a few lines of code:

http://melander.dk/articles/alphasplash/

Answer (score 1):

The basic TImage is capable of displaying a PNG image and alpha-blend-it to whatever is behind it. You just need to add the "pngimage" unit to the uses clause of your form. You didn't mention the version of Delphi you're on: Delphi 2010 has this unit, but I have no idea with what version of Delphi they started shipping it. For Delphi 7 I know for sure you'll need to find the open source "pngimage".

If you need to do this when the user moves in and out of your control, consider caching the state images in bitmaps: it will be faster at runtime and you can use a single TImage that shows the current image, you don't need two overlapping TIMage controls.

Comment: It's capable of alpha-blending a PRE-BLENDED .png artwork. But it doesn't let you blend dynamically at runtime with a variable Alpha value of your choice. At least not without writing a pile of code.